# Publishing to SNS from Lambda in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-vpc

I am trying to publish to SNS from a Lambda in a VPC but my Lambda hangs and eventually times out after a minute or so.

Based on [Securing messages published to Amazon SNS with AWS PrivateLink | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/securing-messages-published-to-amazon-sns-with-aws-privatelink/) and similar articles I have created a VPC endpoint like so:

```
      Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
      Properties:
        PrivateDnsEnabled: true
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - security-group-id
        ServiceName: com.amazonaws.ap-southeast-2.sns
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet1-id
          - subnet2-id
        VpcEndpointType: Interface
        VpcId: vpc-blahblah
```

This still results in my Lambda hanging when publishing to SNS. [How to publish to SNS from Lambda within VPC using VPC Endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50170420/how-to-publish-to-sns-from-lambda-within-vpc-using-vpc-endpoint) recommends a AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress which allows all TCP traffic from the VPC's CIDR as well but that doesn't work either.

My Lambda and the VPC endpoint are in the same security group and there are ingress rules to only allow incoming connections from MySQL from some places and all traffic from the VPC as well (as mentioned previously).

What am I missing to make my Lambda be able to publish to an SNS topic?

Comment: What are SGs, for the endpoint and lambda.

Comment: I assume that the lambda has been set to work with vpc, e.g. it has correct [execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html#vpc-permissions)

Comment: Is making any network setting necessary for using SNS from a VPC or No VPC Lambda? I thought as long as you have the IAM permission to SNS, the Lambda should be able to work with SNS service
I guess SNS IAM permission for the calling Lambda should suffice, if not it needs VPC endpoint for SNS enabled to the Subnet in which Lambda is deployed

Comment: Lambda creates network interface in your vpc. Thus it needs execution role for that before it can do anything in the vpc. In the link I posted earlier, the role is explained.

Comment: yea the Lambda execution role permission is required

Comment: @Ani So it works now after updating the role?

Comment: I tried adding ec2:CreateNetworkInterface, ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces and ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface to the list of allowed permissions (for resource arn:aws:eni:*:*:* - is that right?).
The Lambda and VPC endpoint are in the same security group which aside from the allow all TCP for the VPC has some other rules to restrict access to the RDS in the security group (allow 3306 from some places).

Answer (score 3):

To reproduce your situation, I created:

- An **Amazon VPC** (with one subnet and **no Internet Gateway**)
- A **VPC Endpoint for Amazon SNS**, with:

  - An access policy permitting all inbound traffic
  - A **security group** permitting all inbound access from the CIDR of the VPC
- An **Amazon SNS topic** with a SMS subscription to my phone
- An **IAM Role** for use by the Lambda function that permits usage of Amazon SNS
- An **AWS Lambda function**:

  - With the above IAM Role
  - With a security group permitting all outbound traffic
  - Attached to the private subnet in the VPC

My Lambda function is:

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Send message to SNS
    MY_SNS_TOPIC_ARN = 'arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:111111111111:foo'
    sns_client = boto3.client('sns')
    sns_client.publish(
        TopicArn = MY_SNS_TOPIC_ARN,
        Subject = 'From lambda',
        Message = 'Hello'
    )
```

I then tested it by manually running the Lambda function from the Lambda console.

I **successfully** received the test message on my phone.

Therefore, I suggest that you compare your configuration to the above and try to spot any differences.

I notice that you are **deploying via CloudFormation**, so you could either launch the stack and then compare your resources to what is described, or you might try manually creating the above to confirm that it is working for you, and then compare those resources against your CloudFormation template.

Comment: I believe the default access policy for a VPC endpoint in to allow all inbound traffic so that should be fine.
My VPC has an Internet Gateway though - could that be the problem?

Comment: I did not include an Internet Gateway so that I could prove that the VPC Endpoint was working. If you have an Internet Gateway, then what is your use-case for using a VPC Endpoint for Amazon SNS? (eg It might be for added security.) In such a situation, make sure that the Lambda function is connected to a subnet that has its Route Table updated to point to the VPC Endpoint. A Lambda function in a VPC does not have Internet Access unless a NAT Gateway is configured in the VPC.

Comment: Not sure (I've inherited this code) but the VPC contains an RDS that is accessible from certain public IP addresses so I guess that's why there's an Internet Gateway?
How would I update the route table to point to the VPC endpoint? A VPC endpoint doesn't seem to be something a route table route can know about.

Comment: Actually, it might be automatically configured when the VPC Endpoint is added to the VPC. That's why you need to specify the subnets as part of the VPC Endpoint definition. So, just make sure that the Lambda function is connected to one of the subnets listed in the VPC Endpoint definition. If you have no specific reason to connect the Lambda function to the VPC (eg if you don't need to interact with resources inside the VPC), then it is generally best _not_ to configure the Lambda function to use a VPC.

Comment: Hm, still seems like something is missing. And SNS is an Interface rather than a Gateway service so it shouldn't be a route table issue?

Comment: The security group that you mention - so it should be a new security group with CidrIp the same as the VPC's CidrBlock, and this security group should be passed in the VPC endpoint's security group's list?

Comment: Yes, that is how I configured it. The inbound rule allowed All Traffic from the VPC's CIDR. It was selected when the VPC Endpoint was defined.